# ansible w azure pipeline - how to 'pass' a variable

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ansible

I have an Azure pipeline, in which I call an Ansible playbook. The playbook is run, and eventually I have this task:

```yaml
- name: set fact for pipeline filename
  shell: 'echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=filename]whatever"'
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true
```

Now, Ansible is done exeucting, and I have another Azure pipeline task.

```yaml
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: echo filename
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      echo ${{ variables.filename }}
```

I'm asking this question because the output of the task is empty. I expected `whatever` to display, but it doesn't.

**Q**: What is the proper method to pass variables from Ansible to the Azure pipeline.

Comment: The `##` directives are [Logging commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash). The way that they work is essentially that the Azure DevOps pipeline is scanning the logged output for the prefix. Is your Ansible playbook output going into the pipeline log or is the `echo` only run locally? (I'm not familiar with Ansible and Ansible delegated tasks.)

Comment: Would you please try to run `echo $(filename)` in the Bash task and check what's the result? Are you running the above tasks in the same job or in the different jobs?

Comment: all in one job, let me check...

Comment: The output is: `echo $(filename)`

Comment: @JonathanDodds, it is indeed run locally, as on the container image executing Ansible, hence the `delegate_to: localhost` part. @Ziyang Liu-MSFT, see comments

Comment: @KevinC Is the text `##vso[task.setvariable variable=filename]whatever` in the log of the pipeline run? If it is not (i.e. if the output of `echo` is only local to `localhost`), then the variable will not be set. It sounds like it is local only.

Comment: @KevinC In Ansible, how do you generate custom messages to stdout? It looks like you can use `debug` with a `msg` to print a message string of `##vso[task.setvariable variable=filename]whatever`.

Comment: @Kevin C, I am not familiar with Ansible. If your pipeline and the playbook is running on the same machine and you can use playbook to set environment for the current machine, maybe you can set an environment variable inside your playbook, and use this [environment variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#environment-variables) in the following tasks.